# DevExpress XAF, unable to open Model Editor in .net 6.0

Tags: devexpress, xaf

In VS 2022 and XAF solution, if I configure for .net 6 then the model editor will no longer opens. I get this "Could not find the ModuleBase descendant to build the Application Model."
I can still build the solution.

If the same but I use .net 5 then it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther is a workaround on this post
[Model Editor does not work with .NET 6 projects](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1051661/core-model-editor-does-not-work-with-net-6-projects)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how DevExpress miss such an obvious issue!

Comment: I think there is a fix now https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/T1051661/core-model-editor-does-not-work-with-net-6-projects/